# Getting file based on weird URI provided in manifest.json returns 404

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to get all the files from autodesk forge using the [GET object API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-GET/) 
and there's one file that I am unable to download no matter what, the filename is
`Finishes.Ceilings.Acoustical Tile.Perforated.2x2.White.jpg`.

[Link to manifest.json here](https://pastebin.com/Kcc3thUK)

I have checked the URI and it looks extremely weird as compared to other files.

so... my question is that, is this a bug on Autodesk side or did I not do something correctly before translating my model to SVF?

Comment: This looks like a piece of external resource that needs to be packed together with the model file at the time of uploading. If that’s the case can you follow the instructions [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/show-revit-custom-texture-map-viewer) and try again?

Comment: Well, I found the path to the material in the path for that exact material: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/QVcQeMD).  I manage to find the library but I dont see the jpg file anywhere (probably embedded in the library I think?).  Should I copy the lib into the same folder as the revit file and then pack it into a zip?

Comment: Are you attempting to download the output of Forge Model Derivative service (the SVF file used by Forge Viewer)? If so, this is possible but the process is a bit more involved.

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to download the output of Forge Model Derivative service.

Comment: Any update to this problem?